# Is there a way to manipulate the bits that I shift in C

Tags: c, bit

If I have an int a, which is lets say equal to 0.
Is there a way for me to say left shift 101 into the variable and then in another step shift in 011 into it? Then I could get the int decimal number at the end? It would end up becoming 0b00000000000000000000000000101011.Or should I only use the OR operation.

Comment: shifting is an operation that you do on a value to produce another value. What do you mean by "left shift into a variable" ?

Comment: If you want to inline some assembler, in some flavors you can rotate the bits through the carry flag, then you could genuinely shift in whatever number you wanted. Almost certainly more cycles than just shift + add/or.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't shift bits into the variable; you can OR them in:

```
int a = 0;
a |= 5;
printf("a = %d\n", a);
a <<= 3;
a |= 3;
printf("a = %d\n", a);
```

If your system supports binary constants, you can use those instead of decimals (and you can prefix 5 and 3 with `0` for octal or `0x` for hexadecimal if you prefer — and you can print with a different format according to taste, too).  If the starting value for `a` isn't known to be `0`, you would do a shift-assignment operation before the first `|=` operation.

Eventually, you have to worry about left-shifting a signed integer value such that overflow occurs — that leads to undefined behaviour.  It isn't a problem with the values in the question, though.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to first shift by the required number of bits then perform a bitwise OR of the new data.

```
int a = 0;
a = a << 3;
a = a | 0x5;
a = a << 3;
a = a | 0x3;
printf("a=%x\n", a);
```

( Used separate assignments and operators instead of compound operators to make it clearer to beginners. )

Result:

```
a=2b
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to say left shift 101 into the variable

No. You need to left shift first, then add (or OR) the new value.

```
int eax = 0;
eax <<= 3;
eax |= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 0;
a << 3;
a |= 0x5;
a << 3;
a |= 0x3;
```

There isn't a predefined way to "shift in" a value like that. It wouldn't take much time to write a function that could though.

Answer (score 0):

There is - to my knowledge - no operation that "shifts" a number of bits from one integer into another. The left shift operator always fills the arising spaces with `0`, such that you have to combine it with, for example, an `|`-operation (actually a `+` would have the same effect in your case).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary(int b, int nrOfBits) {
    for (int mask = (1 << nrOfBits); mask != 0; mask >>=1 ) {
        char c = (b & mask) ? '1' : '0';
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    a = (a << 3) | 0x5;
    printBinary(a, 8);printf("\n");
    a = (a << 3) | 0x3;
    printBinary(a, 8);printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When using left shift operators on signed datatypes be careful not to produce undefined behaviour (cf. [cppreference concerting arithmetic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)):

> When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does
>   not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined